# Apache APISIX integration with Keycloak

Tags: microservices, keycloak, api-gateway, apache-apisix

I have a few microservices that validate and identify the user using Keycloak as below

[image]

---

I now want to place the Apache APISIX API Gateway before the microservices.

Apache APISIX has a [plugin for Keycloak](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/authz-keycloak). **Can the plugin do the following such that the validation is removed from all the microservices?**

- Validate the `access_token` from the user
- If valid, forward the request to the microservice

[image]

---

**Note**

[This article](https://apisix.apache.org/blog/2021/12/10/integrate-keycloak-auth-in-apisix/) gives details on how to integrate the Keycloak plugin such that the user will have to authenticate using Keycloak (using a single Keycloak `client_id` and `client_secret`). In my case, however, each user will have a different `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the plugin do the following such that the validation is removed from all the microservices?

Yes, it can. The Apache APISIX can validate the access_token, also can add the `user_info`, `id_token` to the upstream.
For more details, you can refer to the plugin docs of Apache APISIX. https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/openid-connect.

> In my case, however, each user will have a different client_id and client_secret.

Now, Apache APISIX doesn't support setting more than one client id of openid-connect in a route.Maybe you can create more routes, each route for each client? And use `Host` to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works as expected. Moreover, the openid-connect plugin authenticates `access_token` generated using different `client_id` and `client_secret`